# Spring AbstractApplicationContext objects in Springboot holding memory as part of ApplicationShutdownHooks causing OOM - GC Overhead Limit exceeded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have Spring Boot based Microservices which uses Spring Web, Spring Actuator based health endpoints, Spring Cloud Consul configuration for accessing the configuration stored in consul and Spring Cloud Vault for restoring the vault secrets. This micro services are deployed as docker containers on docker swarm

When services are started - they start up and work fine, but over a period of time they start throwing But over a period of time, we are seeing that this services are throwing following exceptions and causing OutOfMemoryExceptions - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

**Stack trace #1**

**Logger class - org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory**

**Message** - Destroy method on bean with name

```
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception


java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@64008f91: startup date [Tue May 15 13:01:18 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
```

**Stacktrace #2**

**Logger class - org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication**

**Message** - Application startup failed

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.databases.VaultConfigDatabaseBootstrapConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:299)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 48 frames truncated
```

**Heapdump Analysis**

Whenever we got heapdump we see that java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks is occupying almost 85% memory which internally has java.util.IdentityHashMap holding objects of org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext. Checkout the image

[Heap Dump Dominator Tree showing java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks holding memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56oeH.png)

Can anybody help here to understand what is causing this? Also it would be great if somebody can help understand why so many instances of org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext would be created.

Comment: Here is sample application class

Comment: Here is sample spring boot application class for microservice
Annotation for Slf4j
Annotation for SpringBootApplication
Annotation for ComponentScan("com.xyz")
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Some other micro service has quartz scheduler and configurations for applications are loaded from consul.

Comment: Could you share other Configuration classes from one of these apps? (Edit your post)